# Caching web requests in Excel UDF (javascript API)

Tags: excel, caching, excel-formula, user-defined-functions, javascript-api-for-office

The excel javascript API can request data from an external service as outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-web-reqs

However, imagine a UDF that must retrieve contiguous parts of a database or API. Each cell would need to call out to the server repeatedly and a lot of unnecessary requests and latency pile up.

Is it possible to batch up these requests, i.e.

- 1. detect the start/end of the range
- 2. fetch the data in a single request
- 3. update the range in Excel asynchronously (to not block the UI)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-batching is looking interesting

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Excel-custom-functions/Batching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwN7lZPbYXE might solve some of this / could be the basis for such query fusion.